# << operator priority with string comparison

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        string line1("Mike");
        cout << line1 < "mike" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The code above is running correctly only if i use parentheses around the comparison. I think this is happening because the priority of those operations. Can somebody explain this to me? Thank you

Comment: you already seem to know why, details you can find here:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: actually I dont understand the question. Yes `<` has lower precedence than `<<`, so what else you need explained?

Comment: SO is not a substitute for a good book explaining the basics of the language.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: i got it now. Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that's what i'm asking. if the `<` has higher precedence than `<<`, than why the code above is wrong?

As per the [operator precedence rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of C++ the *bitwise left shift operator* `<<` has higher precedence than *the relational operator* `<` [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### C++ Operator Precedence
>
> [...] Operators are listed top to bottom, **in descending precedence**.
>
> **Precedence** : **Operator**
>
> [...]
>
> **7** : `<<` (bitwise left shift operator)
>
> [...]
>
> **9** : `<` (relational operator)

Note the emphasis on *descending precedence* above, meaning **9** does not mean *higher* precedence than **7** in this table, which may be the misinterpretation you made when precedence-ranking of these two operators .

Comment: Thank you. i got it now. I'm currently reading a c++ book for beginners and i didn't know that the << operator used for cout is actually a bitwise left shift operator.